# Re-render SwiftUI view from event

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, watchos, foundation

I have a SwiftUI view whose layout is fully specified by a series of computed properties, but some of those properties change naturally as time goes on. When they've changed enough, there's a notification I can consume, and I'd like to re-render the view at that point. The thing is, I don't have any additional state to keep around, and I'd rather not keep dummy state just to force a re-render. How can this be done?

Specifically, imagine a view that simply displays the current day:

```swift
struct TodayView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(Date.now.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted))
    }
}
```

If the user remains on this screen as the clock ticks past midnight in their time zone, the view will not be refreshed to display the new day. However, the system posts [`.NSCalendarDayChanged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1408062-nscalendardaychanged) when that happens (I know there's not a guarantee about it happening specifically at midnight, but consuming this notification is good enough for my use case)

I'd like to have my view simply consume this notification and trigger a simple re-render, but a simple [`.onReceive(_:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labeledtoolbaritemgroupcontent/onreceive(_:perform:)) doesn't seem to do the trick:

```swift
struct TodayView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(Date.now.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted))
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSCalendarDayChanged) { _ in }
    }
}
```

I'm aware I can keep around some kind of dummy state that isn't actually read, but changing it would trigger a re-render that would basically accomplish this task, like this example:

```swift
struct TodayView: View {

    @State private var dummy = false

    var body: some View {
        Text(Date.now.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted))
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSCalendarDayChanged) { _ in
                dummy.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

However, I'd ideally like to avoid keeping around excess data like that unnecessarily if possible, as it takes a tiny bit more RAM and has an unclear purpose when reading the code for the first time without context. It'd be best if I could just have the view re-render itself from the notification. How would I do that?

Comment: Don't use `Date.now.formatted...` in the `Text` directly. Store that string in an `@State` property and then update that property when you receive the notification. Computed properties are not generally a good fit for SwiftUI views. Your view needs to be driven by observable properties, not computed properties

Comment: That has different semantics, however. The concept of "now" is different every time the property is read, and it's important it stays up-to-date. If I stored it as state, that means I'd be responsible for updating it every time it's about to be read, which isn't very feasible or maintainable

Comment: But that is the essence of SwiftUI - It responds to state changes.  You need to determine what that state change trigger is.  For example, if you wanted to continually update the time, you can use a Timer, but I understand that your example of date is just that; an example, and you actually have a more complex set of properties to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how SwiftUI is all about state, right? Like when the state changes, it tells SwiftUI to update the views. Now, you want to refresh the view when the day changes, but you don't wanna keep some random state around just for the sake of it. I get you, less is more, and we want to keep things clean.

How about we introduce a new friend in our SwiftUI squad, the `EnvironmentObject`? It's like this shared box that different views can peek into, and when something in the box changes, the views get updated.

So, here's a cool idea. We'll create this `DayChangeNotifier` class that is an `ObservableObject`, meaning it will ring a bell for the SwiftUI views when something changes. Inside it, we have a `currentDay` property, and guess what, it's `@Published`. So, whenever `currentDay` changes, SwiftUI knows it's showtime!

Our `DayChangeNotifier` also listens for when the day changes. It's like an alarm clock, when the day changes, it updates the `currentDay` and boom! SwiftUI updates the views.

Now, back to our view, `TodayView`. We just tell it to keep an eye on `DayChangeNotifier` using `@EnvironmentObject`. Whenever `currentDay` changes, `TodayView` is updated. Simple and clean!

Here's how it looks:

```swift
class DayChangeNotifier: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentDay: String = Date.now.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateCurrentDay), name: .NSCalendarDayChanged, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc private func updateCurrentDay() {
        currentDay = Date.now.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)
    }
}

struct TodayView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var dayChangeNotifier: DayChangeNotifier

    var body: some View {
        Text(dayChangeNotifier.currentDay)
    }
}
```

Just make sure our buddy `DayChangeNotifier` stays around as long as we need it. It's gotta keep listening for that day change, right? Inject it into the environment in a parent view or in the App struct and we're good to go! Less clutter, more clarity - that's the way we roll!

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's the cleanest way I derived as well, and it's validating that this was the best way you found, too. Fwiw the details of the hack I had built was to subscribe to the notification with Combine in one of my existing environment objects and have it just call `objectWillChangePublisher.send` directly when it gets the notification. I don't *love* that because it's still not changing any stored state and I need to keep the property computed, but it gets the job done and it's pretty straightforward to adapt for reuse

Comment: Hey, that's a clever workaround you got there! Using Combine's objectWillChangePublisher.send directly to trigger a re-render of the view is a nifty way to sidestep the whole "dummy state" deal. I feel you, it isn't the most elegant because you're not actually changing any state, but it gets the job done, right?

It's like having a friend who's always by the phone and immediately rings up SwiftUI when they get that notification. "Hey, time to freshen up the view, pal!"

Comment: The direct use of objectWillChange.send() can be seen as a hacky approach by some I know because it sidesteps the usual SwiftUI data flow. But it's straightforward and achieves the goal without any unnecessary overhead which is a plus.

The EnvironmentObject solution is more in line with SwiftUI’s design philosophy. It uses a clearly defined state to trigger the view update. But it does add an extra layer of abstraction, which might be a bit of overkill.

This is the best varient solution that I've found that walks the middle: https://gist.github.com/Jxrgxn/2645a407a01add809d146c80f94653b4

Comment: (But I like our approach better ;) hehe)

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, you do have a state that your view depends on, otherwise there would never be a change. The state that your view depends on is not `Date.now`, it's just derived from it.

Personally, I don't think you need an observable object, a simpler solution would look like this:

```
struct TodayView: View {
    @State private var dayString = Date.now.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)

    var body: some View {
        Text(dayString)
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSCalendarDayChanged) { _ in
                dayString = Date.now.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the @State property dayString to store the current day as a string. This way, you're maintaining a piece of state that directly corresponds to what's displayed in the view. When the .NSCalendarDayChanged notification is received, you're updating dayString directly, which then triggers a re-render of the view.

Easier than a separate ObservableObject! It encapsulates all necessary state and behavior within the view itself. This approach ensures that the state, the logic for updating it, and its display are all in the same place. Thx for the insight!

Comment: I realize that `Date.now` is technically state that I depend on, however it's crucial that I read it as a computed property and not store it as `@State`. This is because it's different every time it's read, so manually assigning it to `@State` each time the view refreshes is not practical

Comment: You need to work out what is *driving* the state change. If the date changing isn't *driving* the view refresh, then you can leave it as a computed property and use @State etc for the properties that do drive a view refresh. However, if time is something that changes your view state, use a timer to update it.